# Animation will not fire when wrapped in another function. I've tried so many variations of this code. Please help

Tags: jquery, ajax, global-variables, jquery-animate

Here is what I'm working with.  http://jsfiddle.net/HHBN8/1/  I am trying to animate a class when the data comes back as false, and hide the class when the data comes back as true.  The animation code works fine by itself, but as soon as I throw it into the function it won't fire.  A couple of things,  the document has to be ready for the animation to work, and I'm putting the animation in the same function as the data function because I can't figure out how to access the variable outside that function.  If there is an easier way to do this let me know.  Thanks so much for your help, and keep in mind 3 weeks ago I didn't know what a class was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some alterations like defining the `A` method outside of the other one (*this way you do not have to bind it to the `window.load` event.

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/HHBN8/5/

***note :** you do not have any html .. so there is nothing to animate.. I added some html in the example..*

Comment: thanks for the help.  it works fine on jsfiddle, but when I put it in dashcode it doesn't work for some reason.  image2_template is in the css and html though.

Comment: wait!  nevermind the simulator wasn't firing the animation for some reason, it works great when I deployed it.

Comment: @Davis, glad you got it sorted out :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want. Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KawWC/2/)

```
function getCrossDomainJson(url, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?callback=?",
        data: {
            q: 'select * from xml where url="' + url + '"',
            format: "json"
        },
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: callback
    });
}




function A(MyStatus){

   // alert(MyStatus.someProperty)

    if (MyStatus.someProperty == 'false'){
      function pulsate() {
        $(".image2_template").
          animate({opacity: 0.1}, 1500, 'linear').
          animate({opacity: 1}, 1500, 'linear', pulsate);
      }
      pulsate();
    }else {
        $('.image2_template').animate({
            opacity: 0,
        });
        $('.text3_template').animate({
            opacity: 0,
        });
    }
}


$(document).ready(function(){

    var MyStatus = {};
    getCrossDomainJson("http://xproshowcasex.channel-api.livestream-api.com/2.0/getstream", function(data) {
        // data is in JSON format:
        //alert(data);
        if (data && data.query && data.query.results && data.query.results.channel) {
            MyStatus.someProperty = (data.query.results.channel.isLive)
           //alert(data.query.results.channel.isLive);
            A(MyStatus);
    }

    });

});
```